# Change colour of table row onclick and change back onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm looking for a way to change the background color of a TR onclick and then change it back onclick. Like select and deselect a row.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>No</th>
      <th>Column1</th>
      <th>Column2</th>
      <th>Column3</th>
      <th>Column4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>First item</td>
      <td>Good quality</td>
      <td>Europe</td>
      <td>Cheap</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I found about 20 scripts and all did pretty much the same thing: once the row changed background color once clicked, you couldn't make it go back with another click.

My current CSS code for the table:

```
table {border-collapse: collapse; background: #041c32; }
tr:nth-of-type(odd) {background: #041c32;}
tr:nth-of-type(even) {background: #062949;}
th {background: #1b558e; color: #041c32;}
tr:hover {color:#ffc000; background-color:#000;}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Add a css class maybe `highlighted` that defines the color you want when the row is clicked and highlighted, then if you use jQuery you could simple do

```
$('table tr').on('click', () => $(this).toggleClass('highlighted'));
```

This on click, will add the class if it was not there, or remove if it was there, given the behaviour you wanted

Comment: I don't understand why this doesn't work for me. I can see yours and the others' solution are similar, but it doesn't work for me. Nothing happens when I click inside the table. Here is the full website page if it helps track down an error: http://www.aerosmithbootlegs.com/

Answer (score 0):

add something like:

```
<style>
 .blue{
  background: blue;
}
</style>

<script>
$(()=>{
   $("tr").on('click',(e)=>{
       $(this).toggleClass('blue');
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Naming classes things like "blue" eventually leads to atrocities such as `<style> .blue { background: red; } </style>` — Pick class names that describe what a thing _**is**_ instead of how it _**looks**_, for example `.toggleClass('selected')`

Comment: I was just trying to give an answer to what (s)he was asking for and point him/her to the right direction, her/him design and logic it's up to him/her. If I had to do this myself, I wouldn't even used jQuery

Comment: I understand, and not downvoting you. Many people learn from snippets they find, so I just wanted to point this out for future readers.